# Is turning off ARP a common practice?

Tags: router, arp

I'm just trying to diagnose a problem I and a colleague have had on two separate occasions to swap out an old router with a new one.

Both starting from scratch, we've found that we can't seem to get the router to ping the remote router even when the only thing configured on the router is an IP address on the SFP side.  The link is active.

Is it possible or even common for an internet provider to turn off ARP replies on upstream router to us?  If it is switched off, why would even want to do that?

This is the only thing I can think of as to why it won't respond to ping when it normally responds to ping on the old router and connecting another device as the same address as the remote router on the SFP port responds.

Comment: On layer 2 networks that require ARP, having arp be disabled would break pretty much everything.  ARP is not required on serial links, so it wouldn't be enabled or disabled there.

Comment: So we connect up another router in isolation via sfp and give it the same IP as the upstream router and ping from our router works the upstream router.  When the new router is connected into the real network, there is no ping.  When pinging from an address behind the current router, the upstream router responds.  I should be pointed out that neither of us currently have the password to access the existing router (cisco).  I think we need to press for that.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not, without ARP you'll have no IP link so it's important to have working - and the fact that it works on other equipment means you're getting ARP replies from them in some cases (so it can't be disabled).

More likely is either a hardware or configuration problem on the new router that's preventing it from getting a working layer 2 connection to the ISP's router.

Answer (score 0):

On typical Ethernet networks, technically, you could do static arp entries (if all devices supported it) and not require any ARP traffic, but this is definitely not a common practice.  Is there a chance their router is configured to not respond to ping?

Comment: No because as I mentioned in the question detail, it currently does respond to ping.